# How can I user GETDATE() to retrieve rows

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am a new developer in asp.net, I want to create query that retrieve row based on comparing between DateTime (column in my table) with the current date, I used a lot of things like:

1. `Select * from employee where DateTime = dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0, getDate()))`
2. `Select * from employee where DateTime=Convert(date, getdate())`
3. `Select * from employee where DateTime =getDate()`

The first one, worked correctly but suddenly did not work!
what do you think is the problem?

Comment: can you provide some sample data of the table you are trying to run this query?

Comment: `getdate()` consists of a time part which is instantaneous and can only match for that specific second. After it will be a false condition when you try to check.

Comment: Please edit your question and add enough information to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please fix the typo in the title of your question, also [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try your query like this

```
Select * from employee where convert(date,yourfield) = convert(date,dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0, getDate())))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CAST`to trim time part from the date for the sake of searching.

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE CAST(DateTime AS DATE) = CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE)
```